# Convergence rate of PageRank, the problem when the second eigenvalue is complex

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

As far as I know the Google matrix used to calculate the PageRank is not symetric, that means that some eigenvalues can be complex, furthermore, we know that the second eigenvalue is equal to the damping factor (it's convergence rate to 0 is the same as the convergence rate to the stationary regime which is pagerank).

So in the case where this second eigenvalue is complex, how should I consider the damping factor d which is supposed to be real 0

Comment: Just a comment, but I don't have enough points. Please turn into a comment, sorry: if a Real matrix is symmetric , its eigenvalues are Real * , but the converse is not true, i.e., a non-symmetric matrix may have Real eigenvalues, e.g., consider the $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with $a_{11}=1, a_{22}=2$ , and $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise. It has $1,2$ as eigenvalues. *But the names have been changed to protect the innocent.

Comment: As far as I know, the damping factor $d$ is assumed to be in the interval $(0,1)$ and with $G=dS-(1-d)E$ (where $S$ is stochastic and $E$ a scaled matrix of ones), $|\lambda_2(G)|\leq d$ with the equality if $S$ is reducible. The $d$ is normally recommended to be the "magic" value $0.85$. Now what is the question?

Comment: thx for the comment, I see, I forgot the modulus |λ2(G)|, that answers my question, still I don't understand your claiming that S is stochastic, in the case of dangling nodes, we would have rows of 0 hence the the matrix S wouldn't be row-stochastic, unless we adjust the rows in question by adding democratic teleportation probabilities let's say 1/N. I'd be thankful if you explain to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector consisting of the rankings is mathematically the Perron vector of a stochastic matrix. There are more than one ways to determine the Perron vector. If I remember correctly, Google has actually **never** revealed the algorithm it employed to determine that vector, although an early paper by Brin and Page seems to suggest that the [power method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) was used. So, strictly speaking, it does not make much sense for outsiders to speak of the convergence rate of PageRank algorithm.

If we assume that the power method is used, then the convergence rate is ratio of the **modulus** of the second dominant eigenvalue to the Perron eigenvalue. So, it doesn't matter whether the second dominant eigenvalue is real or nonreal.

By the way, your claim that the second dominant eigenvalue is the damping factor is untrue. It's easy to generate a random counterexample by computer.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I understand now for my question that the answer is all about the modulus, that's enough to answer my question. but concerning the subject of convergence rate, I've seen some papers that prove mathematically that indeed the convergence rate of the power method is the same of d^k--->0 when k--->inf. concerning the second dominant eigenvalue, I've also read on many papers that |λ2(G)|≤d or (|λ2(G)|=d when S is reducible), such as G=dS + (1-d)Q. I'd like if you explain more to me, besides the fact that this question has been answered.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi I don't know what papers you have read, but the claim is wrong. Let $E_m$ denotes the $m\times m$ all-one matrix (so that $\frac1mE_m$ is doubly stochastic). Let $S=\pmatrix{\frac12E_2&\frac14E_4\\ 0&\frac14E_4}$, which is column-stochastic (transpose it if you want a row-stochastic matrix). Then $G=dS+\frac{1-d}4E_4$ is block upper triangular, hence reducible, but the second dominant eigenvalue of $G$ is $\frac d2$, not $d$.

Comment: I don't know the exact origin of those false claims about the second dominant eigenvalue, but an [AMS feature article](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-pagerank) is undoubtedly the culprit for popularising them. If you read the feature article carefully, you will find that this false claim is actually a misinterpretation of the result of a paper in the bibliography. The true result says that **if the raw Google matrix $S$ has at least two irreducible closed subsets**, the second eigenvalue of the weighted Google matrix $G=dS+\frac{1-d}{n}E_n$ is the damping factor $d$.

Comment: Ahh, typo. The $S$ in my counterexample should be $\pmatrix{\frac12E_2&\frac14E_{\color{red}{2}}\\ 0&\frac14E_{\color{red}{2}}}$.

Comment: Thx, it's all clear now, nice great clean math.

Still as you mentioned that article, many articles and papers don't hesitate directly saying that |λ2(G)|=d, well I think that can be understandble and acceptable if we put in mind that they already considered S as reducible (at least two irreducible closed subsets) and that G is calculated to escape the reducibility of S. In general and 99%, S which represents the web graph is reducible to many irreducible closed subsets, hence the claim...

Comment: ...
Still your explanation is the most accurate (or the accurate !) if we take in consideration the rare case where the graph can be irreducible.

Your explanation cleaned all the mess in my mind, thx again !